# the result in c flipped to negative number

Tags: c++, c, operating-system

```
 unsigned int x;
 unsigned int y;
 x = 0x66;
 y = 0x39;
 unsigned z;
 z =  ~x | ~y;
 printf("%d\n",z);
```

my code is like this, and I would like to compute  ~x | ~y, I define z as unsigned, but the z is still the negative number. why? and is this the problem in ~x, so what is the ~x operation in computer.
thank you

Comment: my result is -33, and i don't why

Comment: `%d` prints its input as _signed_. You want `%u`

Comment: @YifanHu Tip: rather than just ask why the number is not as expected, also post what value you do expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are telling `printf` to print a signed input, so it will interpret its input accordingly. Try `printf("%u\n", z);`.

Comment: thx, after modifing my code from %d to %u, my result become 4294967263, the UMAX of 32 bit, it still not my want result.

Comment: @YifanHu: 2^32-1 is 4294967295, not 4294967263. Seems to me that 4294967263 is in fact the correct result.

Comment: o o, i found that i am wrong, so that means then the negation operating in unsigned bit pattern, it transfer the head of all the 32 bits,in this case, apart from 8 bits in the head, so the other bits all remain 1?

Comment: @YifanHu: No, it inverts each bit independently of all the others.

Comment: thx again, so do all the other bits are initialized as 1?

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're confused about, but you have `x = 0x00000066` and `y = 0x00000039`. Inverted, therefore, they become `0xffffff99` and `0xffffffc6`, the OR of which is `0xffffffdf`, or 4294967263 in decimal.

Comment: @YifanHu Perhaps you need to truncate the result to the number of bits you require. E.g. `z = (~x | ~y) & 0xff;` will truncate the result to 8 bits, `z = (~x | ~y) & 0xffff;` will truncate the result to 16 bits, etc.

Comment: it really helps !! thx all !!

Comment: @YifanHu • *...negation operating...* there is no **negation** `-` in the code provided.  The code provided uses **bitwise NOT** `~` (aka bitwise *inversion*, or bitwise *complement*).

Comment: @Eljay: That's pedantry in the extreme, and call it negation is not uncommon. If you search for "bitwise negation" or "logical negation" online, you'll find tons of results, from reputable sources, and for good reason.